# In mongo mms account, how to remove voice/sms authentication

Tags: mongodb-mms

I have setup mongodb mms account for one of the servers.
As a login authentication i selected for both password and sms code.
But now i donot want sms code. donot see a way to remove that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two factor authentication is not optional (refer blog here: http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/now-available-two-factor-authentication-mms-backup-google-authenticator - "MMS requires two-factor authentication to ensure that only authorized users can access sensitive data and perform certain operations ..."), but you can choose if you want to receive an sms or to use the Google Authenticator app. To modify the settings for your account:

1. Log in to MMS
2. Click account in top right > Settings
3. Look for 'Two Factor Authentication' on the profile page and click the edit icon next to SMS
4. Enter your verification code from the SMS you will be sent
5. Toggle between Google Authenticator and SMS